# less: how to import multiple css?

Tags: css, import, less

I'm learning less and let me know how I can create a file "styles.css" is called and within this to import other files less to have more orderly and separate my css ie;

I want to customize the header in one less file, and what is going on in other less contect file

if this is not possible?

so when compiling everything is saved within my library styles.css

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, just use `import` in you `style.less`:

```
@import "header.less";
@import "body.less";
@import "footer.less";
```

and the three less files will be compiled into the `style.css`

Every `import` possibilities are listed in the doc : http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options